# R/W csv with dynamic size of columns to a lookup table by CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a csv data like this

|  | Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | ... | ValueN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key1 | Value11 | Value12 | Value13 | ... | Value1N |
| Key2 | Value21 | Value22 | Value23 | ... | Value2N |
| Key3 | Value31 | Value32 | Value33 | ... | Value3N |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| KeyN | ValueN1 | ValueN2 | ValueN3 | ... | ValueNN |

which have dynamic size of columns.
I want to load it to a lookup table

```
dictionary<string, dictionary<string, string>> lookup_table
```

so I can get data by

```
data = lookup_table[key_name][header_name]
```

Furthermore, I have to write back to csv if data got changed.
How should I create my class and map to read/write it?
csvhelper version = 28.0.1

Comment: I would suggest either of two ways: (1) Create a model class reflecting the columns in your CSV. Read the CSV records as a collection of your model class, then populate your dictionary-of-dictionaries from that colletion. Or, (2) read the CSV "manually" with CsvHelper's CsvReader and populate your dictionary-of-dictionaries directly with the data read from the CSV with CsvReader. For writing, it would be the reverse process: either creating a collection of the model class and then serializing the collection to CSV, or writing the dictionary-of-dictionaries "manually" using CsvWriter.

Comment: For the first approach (i.e. using a model class that reflects the CSV structure), you might need to at least explicitly map the first column/field of the CSV to the respective model class property (https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/). For my 2nd suggested approach, the CsvHelper documentation offers a handy example of how to consume CSV without using a model class: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/

Comment: 1.May you give more detail of making a model class with unknown size of column? I find an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134421/dynamic-creation-of-columns-using-csvhelper. Do you have another suggest? 
2. Does manually method comsume more time than model class method?

Comment: If you don't know in advance how many columns a CSV file has, then it is in my opinion better to directly read the CSV records with the help of CsvReader without defining a model class. In my previous comment, i gave a link of an example in the CsvHelper doc that illustrates how to read records from a CSV.

Comment: Is the header for the first, key, column actually missing, or just empty? Might you [edit] your question to share a sample of your CSV as **text** rather than as a screen shot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)* which also applies to CSV text.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue` is defined to be an **unordered** collection of key/value pairs.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0): *The order in which the items are returned is undefined.*  So if you *have to write back to csv if data got changed* then when you do so the order or the rows may get completely changed.

Answer (score 1):

Except for @dbc comment that the order of the items may change due to the **unordered** nature of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, this should work.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var lookup_table = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader(",Header1,Header2,Header3\nKey1,value11,value12,value13\nKey2,value21,value22,value23"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {       
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        
        var headerLength = csv.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord.Length;
        var header = csv.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord;
        
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var key = csv.GetField(0);
            lookup_table.Add(key, new Dictionary<string, string>());
            
            for (int i = 1; i < headerLength; i++)
            {
                lookup_table[key][header[i]] = csv.GetField(i);
            }
        }
    }
    
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var headers = lookup_table.First().Value.Keys.ToList();
        
        csv.WriteField(string.Empty);
        
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            csv.WriteField(header);
        }
        
        csv.NextRecord();
        
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> entry in lookup_table)
        {
            csv.WriteField(entry.Key);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
            {
                csv.WriteField(entry.Value[headers[i]]);
            }
            
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The order of data is ignorable. Thanks for example code.